# ACF repeater field with multiple subfields checked by today date

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have a custom field (repeater) called "today". In it, i have a "choose the calendar date" subfield.

On a product (woocommerce) i've added 1, 2, 3 or more dates. The return date its like dd/mm and I get the today date to compare with like date(d/m).

The problem is that the loading time is extremly big and i get no results...

What i've tried:

```
$today = date('d/m');

$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'product',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'today_$_mdate',
            'compare'   => '=',
            'value'     => $today
        )
    )
);

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php else:
    echo "No prods"; endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query();
```

The repeater field: `today`

The subfield: `date`

Why i cant return only the products that has the repeater field subfield set to 
today's date?
It doesnt even return the products.

This is the product handle in WP: http://prntscr.com/kkobbb

This is the custom field set: http://prntscr.com/kkobqo

```
$today returns `20/08`
```

**New approach:**

```
$today = date('d/m');

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$products = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $products->have_posts() ) {
  echo '<ul>';
    while ( $products->have_posts() ) {
        $products->the_post();
        if( have_rows('today') ):
            while ( have_rows('today') ) : the_row();
                the_sub_field('mdate');
            endwhile;
        else :
            // no rows found
        endif;
    }
  echo "</ul>";
}

wp_reset_query();
```

Still huge amount of loading time... and the message `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted... in wp-includes/plugin.php on line 179`

But atleast, i can filter the products based on its repeater subfield.

Comment: What is 'Save format' of your date field?

Comment: @OutsourceWordPress Sorry for the delayed answer. My save/return format is set to custom d/m as in this picture: http://prntscr.com/kkpcyc

Comment: Can you ensure that you are using latest version of ACF and ACF Repeater plugins?

Comment: It's pro version and its fully updated. No updates required for my plugins.

Comment: Then may be your memory limit very low, try adding this to 'wp-config.php' - `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );` and check again.

Comment: It s already set to 512 and i've got the error: 536870912 bytes exhausted

Comment: The problem seems to be the hard loading. Why? I loop through all products, then check for repeater and its subfield. the subfield verify a condition and thats it...

Comment: Can you remove ACF Repeater loop and check whether product titles displaying fine?

Comment: It was made with a check button before and worked fine. Every detail was just fine and was loaded pretty fast

Comment: The problem was that i couldnt check using a check button if the product should list today or tomorrow so i had to check the current date, today date, and add a specific date for the product

Comment: And i came with this solution but the listing is extreamly heavy even for 3-4 products i have to test with

Comment: Do you mean just using ACF Repeaters causing the heavy load and rest fine?

Comment: Yeap... I've tried to just use the 'get_field' function and added the id in the loop and started to behave like it was loading the entire wordpress with all querys all in the same time... Check the new approach please

Comment: Okay, can you add `wp_reset_query();` above your `$products` loop?

Comment: Good ideea, lemme try

Comment: Nah... still hard loading...

Comment: Its very strange since working fine for me :( Can you change the ACF Repeater name `today` to some other thing and try again?

Comment: It's working just fine! switched from repeater to radio and i can list the prods very fast

Comment: Okay fine then :)

Comment: The problem is not fixed... Will you come with a fix for this? Added a custom field with a single date picker and its working fine... Seems like only repeater field cause problems

Comment: But the thing is i really need to add date picker subfields... so i can add more than 1 date for a single product

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178347/discussion-between-outsource-wordpress-and-ozzie).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is fixed. From ACF custom field settings just set the repeater field schema to line and not table. For me it was set to table and i had biiiig loading time and crashes.